# MySQL PHP Hack Prevention / DB backup?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, backup

Well, I finally finished my site (Just learned PHP and MySQL) So I'm wondering what are some of the most common ways hackers get in and how can I prevent it... I have already been informed of `addslashes();`, `mysql_real_escape_string();`, and `strip_tags();`.
What else can I do? (With explanation please) And what are the best ways to back up my tables and my database? (I use phpMyAdmin if that matters) Thanks so much for all the programming advice so far! I love this site and I love you all!

Comment: This is too general a question for the StackOverflow Q/A format. Read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.php) to start, and come back if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Backup regularly. You can automate this process with some hosting providers. Otherwise, a simple `Export` from phpMyAdmin should suffice. All tables, all data. Dump to an SQL file, and zip. The hosting providers that offer complete backup will often include all of your other filesystem data too (*`.php` files, anything in your webroot, etc.*)
- Consider using instead [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The inherent security provided through [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) is much better than essentially rolling your own through a combination of `addslashes()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `strip_tags()`, not to mention it sets you up to support additional database technologies (*with less of a transitional period than from the explicit `mysql_*` API*) Transitioning to PDO after you've "finally finished your site" may seem fruitless, however the payoff is much larger in the portability and security offered therein.

Oh yea, and merry `[enter holiday of your choosing]`!

Comment: $holiday = "Christmass"; HAhaha! ;) Thanks, I'll look into it! This is a great answer but I'm gonna leave the question open a little longer before choosing a "correct" answer so I can get all loads of advice! thank you so much! +1.

Comment: No problem @AlbertRenshaw -- Definitely give the answer to whomever offers the most relevant information. As has been mentioned in a comment, the question is a bit vague and general, perhaps if you edited to offer up some specific circumstances you were concerned about (*more specific than "I'm worried about XSS and losing backups"*) I'll edit to match the specificity when you do.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend the use of an abstraction library like PDO.

It's not worth your while to ensure your SQL statements are safe, leave it to a core framework like PDO.